# Reading all the RDF files in a directory

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I am trying to read all the RDF files in a directory, but it seems that I am only reading the first file. I first get the file names using File object and then try to iterate through them, reading each one. I dont know what to do if I have to do something like

```
model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

after each iteration or close the input and output streams or something else. My code so far follows:

```
String inputFileName  = "";
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
StringWriter out;
File folder = new File("D:/filepath");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
String result="";

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    inputFileName= listOfFiles[i].getName();
    inputFileName = "D:/filepath/" +inputFileName;
    System.out.println(inputFileName);
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( inputFileName );

    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }

    model.read(in, "");
    String syntax = "RDF/XML-ABBREV"; 
    out = new StringWriter();
    model.write(out, syntax);
    result = out.toString();
    //  extractSomethingFrom(result);
    model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: When I wrote my answer, I'd assumed, from “it seems that I am only reading the first file,” that it seemed like that to you because the model only contained the triples from one file.  Based on your comments on my answer, I'm not so sure about this anymore.  _Why_ do you think this is only reading the first file?  What happens if you add, after `inputFileName= listOfFiles[i].getName();` a print statement like `System.out.println( inputFileName );`?  How many files do you see being touched?  (The second part of my answer that uses `Files.walkFileTree` might address that issue, too, though.)

Answer (score 1):

### The problem with the existing code

`Model.read` *adds* statements to model, so code like

```java
Model model = ...
for ( ... ) {
  model.read( ... );
}
// do things with model
```

will give you a model containing all the triples from all things that you've read.  However, you're assigning a new, empty model to `model` on each iteration when you do

```java
model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
```

inside the loop.  That's why each time you write out the model you're only seeing the triples from the file that you read on that iteration.

The following code demonstrates this behavior.  There are two strings containing RDF text, and you can see the effect of `read`ing them successively with and without creating a new model in between.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class ReadMultipleDocuments {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String text1 = "@prefix : <urn:ex:>. :a :b :c .";
        final String text2 = "@prefix : <urn:ex:>. :d :e :f .";

        final String[] texts = new String[] { text1, text2 };

            // reset determines whether or not a new model is assigned 
            // to model after reading each text.
        for ( final boolean reset : new boolean[] { true, false } ) {
            System.out.println( "* reset = "+reset );
                    // create the first model
            Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            for ( final String text : texts ) {
                            // read the RDF from the text. This is analogous to reading
                            // the data from a file.
                model.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( text.getBytes() ), null, "TTL" );
                System.out.println( "  * after reading, model size is "+model.size() );
                            // if a new model is created and assigned to the variable
                            // model, then the triples read during this iteration will 
                            // no longer be available (since you've lost the model that 
                            // they were in).
                if ( reset ) {
                    model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### How to read the RDF files in a directory into a single Model

This problem is actually made much easier with the new file IO in Java.  You can simply create a model, walk a filesystem, and `read` the contents of each file into the model.  Here's code that does just that:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class ReadRDFFilesInDirectory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Files.walkFileTree( Paths.get( "/home/taylorj/tmp/rdfs/" ), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile( final Path file, final BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                model.read( file.toUri().toString() );
                return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
            }
        });
        model.write( System.out );
    }
}
```

In the directory `"/home/taylorj/tmp/rdfs/"`, I've got three files.

one.n3:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:a :b :c .
```

two.n3:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:d :e :f .
```

three.n3:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:g :h :i .
```

The code reads all of them and puts the triples into `model`.  The output is:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="urn:ex:" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="urn:ex:d">
    <e rdf:resource="urn:ex:f"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="urn:ex:a">
    <b rdf:resource="urn:ex:c"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="urn:ex:g">
    <h rdf:resource="urn:ex:i"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, and I hope it helps.  If it does, be sure to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437).  If something doesn't work about it, come back and comment;  maybe we can get it working.

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I will try the code. In my code the reason why I always do createDefaultModel for each iteration is because 1 rdf file contains only one product item. After the program reads one file, it will insert the data from that rdf file to the other database in form of one record (you see  the comment             //extractSomethingFrom(result); this method will do the job). Another thing is that I want a new  model evertime because I have around 1200 rdf files in that folder and each rdf file contains around 900 lines of data.not sure if I can do the whole read and store in one model

Comment: OK, I think I have some confusion about what your actual problem is, but I'll comment on the question proper, not this answer…

Comment: hi I just found out how to work around thank for you hint using normal file system and for jena I just use query object, queryExecution and finally get the resultset using execSelect method then an object QuerySolution. wow have to read a lot haha

Comment: @Danny So what did the problem end up being?  I'm still not clear exactly what the problem was.  If you found a solution (that different from this one), you should write it up and post it an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) so that others who run into this problem will be able to benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

There also exists a library which "looks at a folder and tries to parse the Linked Data files and then returns what is in the folder in a RDF-graph."

from https://github.com/nicola/folder-to-rdf